# Why won't trait bounds work when placed on an associated type?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a generic `Iterator` which uses an internal value to compute a numeric sequence. At each step, several operations are applied to the internal value to compute the next value in the sequence. I can put the trait bounds for these operations on the `Iterator` implementation itself and everything is dandy, but if I move them to the associated type, the compiler is unable to infer the correct trait implementation.

Here is a contrived example which demonstrates the problem. This iterator adds one to the internal value and doubles it. Starting with an internal value of 1 it will produce the sequence 4, 10, 22, 46...

This requires `Add` and `Shl<usize>` trait bounds on `MyType::InnerType`, as wells as `From` bounds for converting the results of these operations back to `InnerType`.

```
use std::ops::*;

fn main() {
    let iter: MyIterator<f32> = MyIterator::new();
    for (i, val) in iter.take(10).enumerate() {
        println!("{} => {}", i, val);
    }
}

struct MyIterator<T: MyType> {
    previous: T::InnerType,
}

impl<T: MyType> MyIterator<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        MyIterator {
            previous: T::InnerType::ONE,
        }
    }
}

// `Add`, `Shl`, and `From` trait bounds only work when put here...
impl<T: MyType> Iterator for MyIterator<T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        // Add one
        let plus_one = T::InnerType::from(self.previous + T::InnerType::ONE);

        // Multiply by two
        let times_two = T::InnerType::from(plus_one << 1);

        // Save state
        self.previous = times_two;

        // Return value
        Some(T::from_inner(times_two))
    }
}

trait MyType {
    // Want to put `Add`, `Shl`, and `From` trait bounds on InnerType here...
    type InnerType: One
        + Copy
        + Add
        + Shl<usize>
        + From<<Self::InnerType as Add>::Output>
        + From<<Self::InnerType as Shl<usize>>::Output>;

    fn from_inner(val: Self::InnerType) -> Self;
}

impl MyType for f32 {
    type InnerType = u32;

    fn from_inner(val: u32) -> f32 {
        val as f32
    }
}

trait One {
    const ONE: Self;
}

impl One for u32 {
    const ONE: u32 = 1;
}
```

The compiler is unable to determine which `MyType::InnerType::from` method to call:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:28:43
   |
28 |         let plus_one = T::InnerType::from(self.previous + T::InnerType::ONE);
   |                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected std::ops::Shl::Output, found std::ops::Add::Output
   |
   = note: expected type `<<T as MyType>::InnerType as std::ops::Shl<usize>>::Output`
              found type `<<T as MyType>::InnerType as std::ops::Add>::Output`
```

However, if I put these bounds on the `impl<T: MyType> Iterator<T>` using a `where` clause, everything compiles as expected.

Why can the compiler infer which `From` implementation to use when the trait bounds are placed on the `Iterator` impl, but not when they're placed directly on the associated type?

Playgrounds with both working and non-working versions:

- [Working](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=30675dbae682a5c9ea9d481e6dfc01c5) (trait bounds for `MyType::InnerType` placed on `Iterator`)
- [Not Working](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f5a6dce3756d0643b5af8ac5e6319088) (trait
  bounds for `MyType::InnerType` placed on associated type directly)

Comment: You could have just used `Add<Output = Self::InnerType> + Shl<usize, Output = Self::InnerType>` and skipped the `From` entirely, right?

Comment: Wow, thank you. Now I feel silly for littering my code with needless trait bounds and `from` calls. I'm a noob and didn't know you could treat associated types as type parameters. So far I've only considered them as outputs of trait implementations.  
I know you didn't answer the question as posed, but this is a much better solution to my problem anyway. If you submit an answer I'll gladly award it to you. Either way, thanks a bunch.

Comment: This looks very much like an inference bug. You can have some fun with it by adding just one of the `From` bounds to the `impl` block, which will cause the `from` call that uses the other bound to fail with a bad inferred type. Could you open an issue on the [language repo](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust)?